# Adding option to sed for case insensitivity and replacing a string of character in a FASTA file

Tags: bash, unix, sed, fasta

I want to create a file where I can search and find a pattern to be changed in a Fasta file. The command below is creating a .sh script with all the pattern that it should match and change:

```
tail -n +2 scaffold_names_2.txt | while read assemb gcenter refseq genbank ncbi; do echo -ne "sed 's/<$gcenter>/$genbank/g' | " >>script.sh; done
```

My file look like this:

```
#Assembly   Genome Center name  RefSeq Accession.version    GenBank Accession.version   NCBI name
GeoFor_1.0  scaffold40  NW_005054297    JH739887    GPS_002009865
GeoFor_1.0  scaffold112 NW_005054298    JH739888    GPS_002009866
GeoFor_1.0  scaffold41  NW_005054299    JH739889    GPS_002009867
GeoFor_1.0  scaffold130 NW_005054300    JH739890    GPS_002009868
GeoFor_1.0  scaffold54  NW_005054301    JH739891    GPS_002009869
```

The .sh file look like this:

`sed 's/scaffold40/JH739887/g' | sed 's/scaffold112/JH739888/g' | sed 's/scaffold41/JH739889/g' |` ...

But, I want the pattern to be case insensitive. I want to add a `-e` in the `sed 's/<$gcenter>/$genbank/g' | "` command. But, when I add the flag, it's not printing in my script. Any ideas why?

```
tail -n +2 scaffold_names_2.txt | while read assemb gcenter refseq genbank ncbi; do echo -ne "sed -e 's/<$gcenter>/$genbank/g' | " >>script.sh; done
```

After having my script, I delete the last pipe and put the fasta file that I want to search and change pattern.

The end goal is to replace the `Scaffold###` that you see in the string below to a `JH######`.

```
>Scaffold410    275
TGCATTAATATGAGTGTGTGCTGCAAAAGTTCAGGTCATGGTCCGATCATACTTCACATTTTGGTAGCACTTTAAGCAGAGATCGGTTATCCCATTCTGTGGAAGACTCAACACTATCATAAGGTCCCACAGTTTTATTATCCCTCTGCCTCCCGGAATGCCCCCGGCAGTGAGGGGTACCATCTTCTCAGCAGTAAGGATATTCTTCAGGAGTTCCGTGTGAGCTTTCCCGGATTTAGTTCCATTTTTTAAATACTTCCCAATTCTTTGCTTTG
>Scaffold430    374
CTTTGTTAACTGAAAGAGCCTCTAAGTAGATGACCAGTGCTCAGTTAGTACAGTATGAATTTTGTTTAATGGAACAGGAAGATTTAGTATTGAGAAGCGGTTAAGGGTTTAACCCAGCCTCCTGTCTGAATGGACCTGAAGAGGGGGGCCGGGAAGAAACCCATGACTGCATTAAAGTGATAGATCTCCAGACATGGGCTAGGGAAGATTTACAAGACACTCCCTGGCCTGAGGGAGAAAATATGTTTATTGATGAGTCTTCAAGGGTGGCAGAAGGGAAGCGATTTACAGGATACACAATCATTAATGGAAGGAAATTAAAGGAAGGGGGGAGATTGTCACCCACCTGGTCAGTTCAGACAGCAGAGCTGTAT
```

I'm using the bash command to do this. But even after the replacement of the `-e` flag it's not working.

Comment: What is your expected output? It seems to work fine on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: I think it's just because the file was appending: `sed -e 's/<scaffold40>/JH739887/g' | sed -e 's/<scaffold112>/JH739888/g' | sed -e 's/<scaffold41>/JH739889/g' | `

Comment: Oh, you didn't delete the first script.sh after you modified your call?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `i` flag at the end, for example `'s/<$gcenter>/$genbank/gi'` ?

Comment: I don't understand the `i` flag. It edits files in place?

Comment: `-i` extension
             Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not
             recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk
             space is exhausted, etc.

Also: non-standard FreeBSD extensions and may not be available on other operating systems. (only for mac, linux)

Comment: Where do you see a `-i` in `'s/<$gcenter>/$genbank/gi'` ? On the other hand, please not that variables will not get expanded in a single quoted bash string. Meaning `'$foo'` doesn't work. `"$foo"` does work.

Comment: I don't see the gI, only the flag `-i` Maybe talking about `i\` here: `[1addr] i\ text Write text to the standard output.`. I tried it and it changes nothing.

Comment: The `i` flag for case insensitivity is part of the search command `s/../../`. Where a `g` (as OP has) on the end means "global" (i.e. don't stop at the first replacement), an `i` means case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm late, but maybe this will serve to another people too.

To resolve the OP question, he has to create a script.sh like this:

```
sed -e 's/scaffold40/JH739887/gi' -e 's/scaffold112/JH739888/gi' -e 's/scaffold41/JH739889/gi' ...
```

- `-e` allows to include various scripts in the same `sed` command.
- `s/<searchText>/<replaceText>/gi` search and replace **`g`** Globally and **`i`** Ignoring case

---

That said, I think that you are really trying to do is replace the column *"Genome Center name"* with the *"GenBank Accession.version"* in your data file.

If that's the case, it's possible with this `awk` command:

```
awk '{ if(NR>1)$2=$4; print }' scaffold_names_2.txt > scaffold_names_2.new.txt
```

**Explanation**

- `awk` is a programming language (C like syntax) that works over lines in text files (one line each time).
- `NR` contains the current record number
- `$i` contains a field inside the current line (`$1`: 1st field, `$2`, 2nd, and so on)
- `print` prints current line.

**Execution**

```
$ cat scaffold_names_2.txt
#Assembly   Genome Center name  RefSeq Accession.version    GenBank Accession.version   NCBI name
GeoFor_1.0  scaffold40  NW_005054297    JH739887    GPS_002009865
GeoFor_1.0  scaffold112 NW_005054298    JH739888    GPS_002009866
GeoFor_1.0  scaffold41  NW_005054299    JH739889    GPS_002009867
GeoFor_1.0  scaffold130 NW_005054300    JH739890    GPS_002009868
GeoFor_1.0  scaffold54  NW_005054301    JH739891    GPS_002009869

$ awk '{ if(NR>1) $2=$4; print}' scaffold_names_2.txt > scaffold_names_2.new.txt

$ cat scaffold_names_2.new.txt
#Assembly   Genome Center name  RefSeq Accession.version    GenBank Accession.version   NCBI name
GeoFor_1.0 JH739887 NW_005054297 JH739887 GPS_002009865
GeoFor_1.0 JH739888 NW_005054298 JH739888 GPS_002009866
GeoFor_1.0 JH739889 NW_005054299 JH739889 GPS_002009867
GeoFor_1.0 JH739890 NW_005054300 JH739890 GPS_002009868
GeoFor_1.0 JH739891 NW_005054301 JH739891 GPS_002009869
```